# How to check the packets in wireshark while doing the internet

Tags: networking, wireshark

I am using Wireshark first time.Can we see the packet in wireshark while having the internet on the laptop(or PC).

But I don't see any packet in wireshark.While I have internet connection.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the interface by clicking on "Capture->Interfaces". If it still doesn't work, its better if you go through wireshark documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Which you're using the operating system?

If you are using Ubuntu:

- Open terminal and write 'sudo su' for root user. You can write 'wireshark' on console. it opens.

  $sudo su

  $password:

  $wireshark

and Choose one more interfaces to capture and start click.

If you are using Windows, you must install WinPcap. After wincap installation, you can capturing. http://www.winpcap.org/